# How to automatically position the cursor BETWEEN method braces after typing the closing brace in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever I create a method signature in VS 2008 (C#), I type the two braces:

public void Something() {}

This leaves the cursor to the right of the closing brace.  Then I have to use the arrow keys to reposition the cursor in between the braces.  Is there a better way to do this without using the arrow keys?

I'd expect it to place the cursor in between the braces when I type the closing one so I can start typing code.

Comment: You should really mark the correct answer as such, giving the answerer credit.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have vs2008 at the moment. Assuming VS2008 still supports this, you could use code snippets. Mess with below til you get what you need. (See Tools|Code Snippets Manager)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>b</Title>
            <Shortcut>b</Shortcut>
            <Description>Braces with cursor inside</Description>
            <Author>CrashCodes</Author>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[{
                     $end$
            }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe Resharper does this. Not sure if there is a free option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a macro to do insert curly braces after the cursor and place the cursor on the line in between them

```
 Sub InsertCurlyBraces()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "{"
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine(2)
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "}"
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.LineUp()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could record a macro that inserts the } then moves the cursor and then assign the macro to  the shift+] key combo, so that your closing curly bracket always performs your macro.

Answer (score 0):

CodeRush does this as well.